# vim diff fffmpeg output using command substitution

Tags: bash, macos, vim, terminal, neovim

Why doesn't this work:

```
vim -d <(ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 2>&1) <(ffmpeg -i vid2.mp4 2>&1)
```

and how can I get it to work?

Currently it just clears my screen completely and causes my terminal to freeze, completely unresponsive to everything ctrl-c ctrl-d and ctrl-z. I have to quit my terminal every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `ffprobe` (comes with `ffmpeg`) if you want an output suitable for diffing:

```
$ vim -d <(ffprobe -i vid1.mp4 2>&1) <(ffprobe -i vid2.mp4 2>&1)
```

> Why?

`ffmpeg` is a media converter that outputs a lot of things during processing, including some information on the source file. Using it without providing an output file/stream/whatever only to get information on the source file is not how it is supposed to be used and, well… it just doesn't work correctly anyway: you get your information but the terminal may be left in a weird state and the operation returns a non-zero status.

By using `ffmpeg`, you are essentially relying on a side-effect of using the wrong tool incorrectly.

`ffprobe`, on the other hand, exists specifically for getting information on the source file.

By using `ffprobe`, you are relying on the expected outcome of using the right tool correctly.

---

That said, `ffprobe` probably shares a lot of code with `ffmpeg` because you need that `2>&1` hack to make its output Vim-friendly. Oh well…

Comment: "the terminal is left in a weird state" do you know why?

Comment: I have zero knowledge of `ffmpeg`'s internals, sorry. Rewording it to not appear as the expert I am not.